# Android. SCREEN_ON reason

Tags: android

Can I get a reason why screen is on when I use BroadcastReciever for SCREEN_ON?(It is user have pressed on/off button on phone, or it is some app for example alarmclock ringing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerManagerNotifier(Notifier.java) is where the ACTION_SCREEN_ON is being broadcasted whenever the system turns on the screen.

https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/services/java/com/android/server/power/Notifier.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base

```
mScreenOnIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
mScreenOnIntent.addFlags(
    Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
```

As you can see it from the above, the broadcasted intent does not contain any info on the reason for being turned on. So, you are not able to distinguish the reason from the BroadcastReciever for ACTION_SCREEN_ON.